# 'Aside from' Vs 'Besides'

Tags: word-choice, differences

I have come across few sentences with the phrase 'aside from' where I felt 'besides' would have been a good choice.

Is there any difference in the usage of the two or can both be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [*besides*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/besides): *additionally*
- [*aside [from]*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aside): *excluding*